# How to get balance from transaction table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have transaction table on my postgresql server with schema like this

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_transaction
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  id_coa integer,
  date_trx date,
  amount numeric(15,2),
  dc character varying(1)
);
```

And data like this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_transaction (id, id_coa, amount, date_trx, dc)
VALUES
   (1, 1, 100, '2020-01-31', 'D'),
   (2, 2, 100, '2020-01-31', 'D'),
   (3, 3, 100, '2020-01-31', 'D'),
   (4, 1, 100, '2020-02-01', 'D'),
   (5, 1, 50, '2020-02-01', 'C'),
   (6, 1, 200, '2020-02-02', 'D'),
   (7, 2, 150, '2020-02-01', 'D'),
   (8, 2, 70, '2020-02-01', 'C'),
   (9, 2, 120, '2020-02-02', 'D'),
   (10, 3, 200, '2020-02-01', 'D'),
   (11, 3, 120, '2020-02-01', 'C'),
   (12, 3, 130, '2020-02-02', 'D');
```

From the data above, if I query from 2020-02-01 to 2020-02-02, I want result like this below:

```
| id  | id_coa | date_trx   |beginning_balance| debit  | credit |
| --- | ------ | ---------- |-----------------| ------ | ------ |
| 4   | 1      | 2020-02-01 | 100.00          | 100.00 | 0      |
| 5   | 1      | 2020-02-01 | 200.00          | 0      | 50.00  |
| 6   | 1      | 2020-02-02 | 150.00          | 200.00 | 0      |
| 7   | 2      | 2020-02-01 | 100.00          | 150.00 | 0      |
| 8   | 2      | 2020-02-01 | 250.00          | 0      | 70.00  |
| 9   | 2      | 2020-02-02 | 180.00          | 120.00 | 0      |
| 10  | 3      | 2020-02-01 | 100.00          | 200.00 | 0      |
| 11  | 3      | 2020-02-01 | 300.00          | 0      | 120.00 |
| 12  | 3      | 2020-02-02 | 180.00          | 130.00 | 0      |
```

My query like below:

```
SELECT 
    jc.id,
    jc.id_coa,
    jc.date_trx,
    CASE
      WHEN jc.dc = 'D' THEN
      jc.amount
      ELSE 0
    END AS debit,
    CASE
      WHEN dc = 'C' THEN
      jc.amount
      ELSE 0
    END AS credit
  FROM tbl_transaction jc
  WHERE jc.date_trx >= '2020-02-01'
    AND jc.date_trx <= '2020-02-02'
  ORDER BY jc.id_coa ASC
```

My question is:

How to get beginning_balance?

- `beginning_balance = SUM(debit-credit) before '2020-02-01' + debit on date_trx` OR
- `beginning_balance = SUM(debit-credit) before '2020-02-01' - credit on date trx`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to calculate the balance using window functions.  Then filter in an outer query:

```
select *
from (select id, id_coa, date_trx,
         (sum(case when dc = 'C' then -amount else amount end) over (partition by id_coa order by id) -
          (case when dc = 'C' then -amount else amount end)
         ) as balance,
             (case when dc = 'C' then amount else 0 end) as credit,
             (case when dc = 'D' then amount else 0 end) as debit
      from tbl_transaction t
     ) t
where t.date_trx >= '2020-02-01' and t.date_trx <= '2020-02-02';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=47cc1b17efc231b0c353e8b13e485c3a) is a db<>fiddle.

BTW, it is strange that credits are subtracted and debits added.

Comment: @Arny . . . That is what `balance` is.  Just run the subquery.

Comment: I change the results I want, because beginning_balance should be added from previews beginning_balance,
Example:
beginning_balance for transaction id 4 is from balance on 2020-01-31, then 2nd onwards beginning_balance would be addition of previous (beginning_balnce+debit) - credit, so on.

Comment: @Arny . . . That was an off-by-one error.  It was calculating the balance *after* the credit/debit on the row was added.  I fixed the answer so this doesn't happen.

Comment: Hi Gordon, i have another question.

Comment: @Arny . . . Then ask a *new* question.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I have more questions if you don't mind. I've followed your advice above, but when I applied it to my query, the results were a little different. The results will be the same when I sort the calculations by ID (over (partition by id_coa order by id)). But the results will be different when you sort them by date (over (partition by id_coa order by date)). My query can be found in DB Fiddle at the following link.
[link]https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivQYX4bfzF3bYCXr5jKSFd/2[/link]
Please advise.
thank you